# exp_expectv returning long after timeout

Tags: c, ipc, expect

I am using expect library for C on linux platform.My intention is to do sftp from one server to another by C program.For that I am creating a **FILE DESCRIPTOR** :

```
d_fd = exp_spawnv(commString, argv);
```

Here comString is a char pointer containing string "sftp" and argv is NULL terminated character array.Then I am creating a FILE pointer and associating that with d_fd. Code is as following:

```
   FILE * d_fp = NULL;
   d_fp = fdopen(d_fd, "rw+");
   if(d_fp == NULL)
   {
       printf("unable to open FILE pointer");
       return;
   }
   if(setvbuf(d_fp, NULL, _IONBF, 0) != 0)
   {
       printf("unable to unbuffer the stream");
       return;
   }
```

Calling this piece of code repeatedly but its not working after 2nd time.At the third time its failing as timeout happens.exp_timeout value is 35 but actually timeout is happening after ~55 minutes.

```
int result = exp_expectv(d_fd, (exp_case*)SFTP_EXP_LOGIN);
```

Comment: Can you test it by replacing `sftp` invocation with something more trivial (e.g. `ls` or `bc`)

Comment: Those are working .. but it specifically need sftp scenario.

Comment: What if you just use an expect _script_ making the same SFTP sessions. Do they work then?

Comment: yes whenever i use script instead of C program it works properly.And with my C code first login and logout for SFTP works fine.. But in subsequent login exp_expectv returns after a long time (after ~55 minutes and that also TIMEOUT though exp_timeout is set to 35).